# Prove that $\mathcal L(V,W)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F^{m,n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working through the proofs in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right but I can't quite crack this one. It's the proposition 3.60, the part that I can't quite crack is the surjectivity proof. Axler says that "to prove that $\mathcal M$ is surjective, suppose $A\in \mathbb F^{m,n}$. Let T be the linear map from $V$ to $W$ such that

$$T_{v_k}=\sum_{j=1}^mA_{j,k}w_j$$

for $k=1,...,n$. Obviously $\mathcal M(T)$ equals A, and thus the range of $\mathcal M$ equals $\mathbb F^{m,n}$, as desired."

The whole thing transcends me, if anyone knows of an alternate proof or can give me a hint on this I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You said that $\mathcal{M}(T)=A$. What do you have to show to establish surjectivity? Every $A$ corresponds to a $T$, which is the case.